# React Infinite scroll doesnt trigger scroll on first page

Tags: reactjs

Its hard to reproduce an example on codesandbox b/c I am getting data from a local database but on my app I am using an infinite scroller from the `react-infinite-scroll-component` library. On the first page of my app I am loading components from my api where the limit is 10. Those 10 items dont go to the bottom of the page because they are displayed in a grid. Because of this the scroller doesnt trigger to loadMore and just shows a loading indicator.

```
const getDataLength = () => {
    return dataSource?.items?.length || 0;
  };
  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={getDataLength()}
      hasMore={!dataSource?.context?.lastPage && !loading}
      next={onLoadMore}
      loader={<Spin className={styles.spinner} key={0} />}
      style={{ overflow: 'hidden', padding: '0px 16px' }}
    >
      <List
        className={styles.list}
        grid={{
          gutter: 16,
          xs: 1,
          sm: 2,
          md: 3,
          lg: 4,
          xl: 5,
          xxl: 6,
        }}
        dataSource={dataSource?.items}
        renderItem={data => {
          return <List.Item>{renderItem(data)}</List.Item>;
        }} />
    </InfiniteScroll>
```

This might be also because of the items are a grid of items compared to a list and it may be messing up the dataLength prop. If anyone knows how to fix this or an example in the same situation please let me know. Maybe on the first iteration I need to load enough Items in the list to get to the bottom of the page? (The List component is from antd)

Comment: When I make the page to the size of mobile screens and scroll, it loads more items. It just doesnt work on big screen where I cant scroll yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I ended up providing a button in loader that will be displayed if the content isn't currently loading

```
loader={
  {loading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <button onClick={loadMore}>Load more</button>
  )}
}
```

Don't really think it's the best way, but provides a  quick workaround at least.